# Connecting vga or hdmi to a microprocessor

Tags: c, hdmi, vga

Hi I am designing  a pcb at the moment I am using the microchip sam9m11 microprocessor, I need to be able to connect it to a monitor/tv through vga or hdmi I have been looking online but I cant seem to find anything. In case it's important I'm looking to use around a 30" monitor also its white text on a black background with some white icons so there is no need for audio or colour

Comment: The hardware aspects of this problem are off topic, but a simple VGA interface can be implemented using R-2R resistor ladders.   Accurately generating the timing signals to achieve the resolution and stability required is software may be difficult.  See http://www.lucidscience.com/pro-vga%20video%20generator-1.aspx for example using 20MHz AVR - you may be able to achieve better with your SAM9, but for a high quality display without consuming a large proportion of your CPU.

Comment: The size of the display is irrelevant.  Resolution, colour depth, aspect ratio and refresh rate are the characteristics you need to define.  For b/w only you can use a single R-2R ladder and connect the single output to the RGB lines.  If you do not need any greyscale you don't even need the ladder.

Comment: Okay thanks very much, I don't know what resolution I can get, I would love 1080 but 720 is sufficient.

Comment: Also the microprocessor has in built video decoding I don't know if that changes anything. Also I am trying to just have one microprocessor but do you think I would need an external processor just for graphics

Comment: As I said, it is off topic, and too complex to discuss in comments. SO is not a discussion forum. Video decoding is irellevant.  A processor with a GPU would help.  Any reason why you wouldn't just use an off-the-shelf board with the capability already? For high quality output you will need video DACs and precise timing, the resistor / software hack is suitable only low resolution / low colour depth implementations.

Comment: How low resolution would we be talking?

Comment: Also according to the data sheet the microprocessor has an inbuilt gpu, it also says it supports 24-bit graphic lcd’s.        See: https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/AT91SAM9M11

Comment: Regarding VGA resolution see the article I linked.  Regarding HDMI, take a look at how other boards do it.  BeagleBone for example used a TDA19988 HDMI framer driven from the processor's LCD controller.  Your processor has an LCD controller - that is the way to go.  An LCD controller is not a GPU - but it is relevant.

Comment: See also https://olimex.wordpress.com/2012/06/12/low-cost-lcd-to-vga-adapter/ simple and very low cost HCD to VGA.